Is there a way to use the NumPy.any() function to find the index of a particular "column" in a 3xAny NumPy array?
I'm working with a 3d "image" and am trying to figure out how to more efficiently map out uniquely joined areas (blood vessels in this case).  I have 1's and 2's along with empty spaces that are 0's.  My current solution for creating a map of where these vessels are is to create an array where
[1 2 0 2
1 2 0 2
1 1 2 2
0 1 0 2] (but in 3D)
would become:
[1 2 0 3
1 2 0 3
1 1 3 3
0 1 0 3]
I use the np.nonzero(arr) to gather the x,y,z coords of all non-zero elements and then I go through and find all the neighboring (front, back, left, right, up, and down; no diagonals) ones that have the same value, while adding these elements to an array that is np.zeroeslike(arr).  While iterating through this array, I would like to be able to remove items from the array created by np.nonzero as I encounter them in my "paint by number" solution (which I use because the software takes the paint by number solution as an input).
Here is my current code:
    def vesselFinder(self, inputVolumeAsArray, minVesselSize):
        import numpy as np
        nonZeroes = np.nonzero(inputVolumeAsArray != inputVolumeAsArray[0][0][0])  # Assume the origin corner is a null value
        visited = np.zeros_like(inputVolumeAsArray, dtype=int)
        nzLen = len(nonZeroes[0])
        v = 1
        for t in range(nzLen-1):
            if not visited[nonZeroes[0][t]][nonZeroes[1][t]][nonZeroes[2][t]]:
                currentVal = inputVolumeAsArray[nonZeroes[0][t]][nonZeroes[1][t]][nonZeroes[2][t]]
                currentPoint = [(nonZeroes[0][t], nonZeroes[1][t], nonZeroes[2][t])]
                while currentPoint:
                    depth, row, col = currentPoint.pop()
                    if (0 <= depth < len(inputVolumeAsArray) and
                        0 <= row < len(inputVolumeAsArray[0]) and 
                        0 <= col < len(inputVolumeAsArray[0][0]) and 
                        not (visited[depth][row][col] > 0) and
                        (inputVolumeAsArray[depth][row][col] == currentVal)):
                        visited[depth][row][col] = v
                        currentPoint.extend([(depth + dd, row + dr, col + dc) for dd, dr, dc in [(1, 0, 0), (-1, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0), (0, -1, 0), (0, 0, 1), (0, 0, -1)]])
                cou = np.count_nonzero(visited == v)
                if (cou < minVesselSize):
                    visited[visited == v] = 0
                else:
                    v += 1
        return visited

Right now, I just check to see if the value in the "visited" array is something other than zero, and if it is, then I just skip over that item.  I would like to avoid some of this waiting time, as I've noticed that with more dense patient scans, my program takes a significantly longer time to run (2 minutes for a sparse image vs 30 for a dense one).

Can you show us the code you've been using and how it works on the sample input?

could you please clarify what "neighboring" means here?

I've edited my post to include the information requested by your comments.  I feel like this is currently an inefficient solution, and want to make it a better solution so that it can eventually practically help researchers looking into the vasculature of the lungs.

This doesn't make as much sense as you think. Showing a 1D array and saying "but in 3D" pretty ambiguous for example. That being said, I think you're looking for a flood fill algorithm, which scikit image has.

I've been trying to avoid adding libraries to the project because it isn't a standalone project, and not all users will have the accessory libraries installed, but they will have Python and NumPy installed as these are included in the application which this extension is written for (I'm not sure if Scikit is included in this or not).  I know we had to scrap the use of Pandas for this reason, and are instead relying on the table functions provided by the base-application.

Look here and here

Then you'll have to implement and package your own implementation. You can start by reading the Wikipedia articles on the subject. They're pretty good, though I would discourage you from trying to reinvent a wheel that's already extremely well hashed out. Good luck

I appreciate the advice :)  I'll look at those and see if I can get it working a bit more efficiently.  This started as a capstone project and this was our team's original solution to this problem, but it's been bothering me that it takes so long to just do this part of the process, so this will be my next area on which to focus.

It looks like you're doing extra work for areas that are smaller than minVesselSize. By setting the entries in visited back to zero after the while currentPoint loop, each of those areas will be traversed once for every voxel inside. You could set them to some placeholder value instead, and replace that value with zero right before returning. Not sure how much that will help, seeing as the regions are small by definition, but it's probably worth a try.

That's actually a really good idea!  They're small, but they can still be up to 500 in size, so that would be potentially 2500 points being checked for a single vessel.  Thank you!
